# Add read more link to page loop

Tags: wordpress

I have this code to show 3 latest pages on a page.

So now there is a page showing content of 3 individual pages. I want each of those 3 pages not to show the full content, but a certain amount of characters. After that there should be a read more link which leads to the individual page.

Could someone help me in the right direction?
Thanks!

```
 <?php
 query_posts(array('showposts' => <number_of_pages_to_show>, 'post_parent' => <ID of the       parent page>, 'post_type' => 'page'));

 while (have_posts()) { the_post();
 the_title(); 
 the_content();
 }

 wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $link = get_permalink($post->ID);?>

<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">read more</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Philip, I feel you should replace

`the_content();` with `the_excerpt();`

Comment: That was easy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code:

```
 add_filter("the_content", "ContentFilter");  

 function ContentFilter($content)  
    {  
   // Take the existing content and return a subset of it  
  return substr($content, 0, 300);  
  }  

remove_filter('the_content', 'ContentFilter'  );
```

hope it helps